Jacobian of a reflection operator
Here is a reflection operator $L(H,V) = 2(H \cdot V)H - V$ that I use in my raytracer.
When sampling microfacets I need to account for its Jacobian determinant. So I tried to directly derive it.
Here is the derivation for a special case where $V=(0,0,1)$
In coordiantes $$L(H) = (2H_xH_z, 2H_yH_z, 2H_z^2 - 1)$$
$$J = \begin {pmatrix}2H_z & 0 & 2H_x\\\ 0 & 2H_z & 2H_y\\\ 0 & 0 & 4H_z\end{pmatrix}$$
So the answer is $$det(J) = 16H_z^3$$
Or in general
$$det(J) = 16(L \cdot H)^3 \quad\quad(1)$$
However this (https://jcgt.org/published/0007/04/01/paper.pdf) paper suggests a different answer $$det(J) = 4(L \cdot H) \quad\quad(2)$$
The resulting image actually looks more plausible with $(2)$. So I am wondering, where did I go wrong with my derivation?

Connected this question and its answer.
